# How to influence the components that are in the slot vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component in which there are 2 buttons and checkboxes that are inserted through `<slot>`. How can I change the checkbox's prop when I click the buttons in the component?

*Checkbox.vue*:

```html
<template lang="pug">
    .field
        label.checkbox(:class="'checkbox_'+badge")
            input(type="checkbox" :checked="checked")
            span(v-if="title") {{ title }} <small v-if="summ">{{ summ }}</small>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "checkbox",
    props: {
        title: {
            type: String
        },
        summ: {
            type: String
        },
        checked: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

*CheckboxGroup.vue*:

```html
<template lang="pug">
    .checkboxgroup
        slot
        button Check all
        button Reset all
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "checkboxgroup"
}
</script>
```

*Usage*:

```
checkboxgroup(checkall="true" dropall="true")
   checkbox(title="200 мм" summ="2" checked style="badge")
   checkbox(title="300 мм" summ="4" checked style="badge")
   checkbox(title="400 мм" summ="5" checked style="badge")
   checkbox(title="500 мм" summ="6" checked style="badge")
   checkbox(title="600 мм" summ="7" checked style="badge")
   checkbox(title="900 мм" summ="8" checked style="badge")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) to pass data to the slot children.

1. In the parent component, define a boolean flag, named "allChecked". Also define methods that toggle the flag (`toggleAllChecked()`) and reset the flag (`resetAllChecked()`):

```js
export default {
  name: "checkboxgroup",
  data() {
    return {
      allChecked: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAllChecked() {
      this.allChecked = !this.allChecked
    },
    resetAllChecked() {
      this.allChecked = false
    }
  }
}
```

2. In the parent component's template, bind `allChecked` to the `<slot>`, and the methods as the button `click`-handlers:

```html
<template lang="pug">
    .checkboxgroup
        slot(v-bind:allChecked="allChecked")
        button(@click="toggleAllChecked") Check all
        button(@click="resetAllChecked") Reset all
</template>
```

3. In the app component, you can use the `checkboxgroup`'s `allChecked` flag through the slot scope (i.e., `checkboxgroup(v-slot="{ allChecked }")`):

```html
<template lang="pug">
    checkboxgroup(v-slot="{ allChecked }")
        checkbox(title="200 мм" summ="2" v-bind:checked="allChecked" style="badge")
        checkbox(title="300 мм" summ="4" v-bind:checked="allChecked" style="badge")
        checkbox(title="400 мм" summ="5" v-bind:checked="allChecked" style="badge")
        checkbox(title="500 мм" summ="6" v-bind:checked="allChecked" style="badge")
        checkbox(title="600 мм" summ="7" v-bind:checked="allChecked" style="badge")
        checkbox(title="900 мм" summ="8" v-bind:checked="allChecked" style="badge")
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-mclaren-o9de6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FCheckboxGroup.vue&theme=dark)

Comment: @ЕвгенийВенеград No problem :)